# Uniform limit of m-homogeneous polynomials over compact subsets of a Banach Space

Tags: polynomials, banach-spaces, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to solve problem 1.2.A from Mujica's book "Complex Analysis in Banach Spaces".

We denote by $\mathcal{P}_a(^mE;F)$ the space of all $m-$homogeneous polynomials from $E$ into $F$, i.e, the mappings $P:E\longrightarrow F$ such that exists a multilinear symmetric $A:E^m \longrightarrow F$ that satisfies:
$$P(x) = Ax^m = A(x,\ldots,x) \quad \forall x \in E$$

> Let $(P_j)$ a sequence in $\mathcal{P}_a(^mE;F)$ such that the limit $P(x)=\lim P_j(x)$ exists for every $x\in E$.
>
> 1. Show that $P\in \mathcal{P}_a(^mE;F)$.
> 2. Show that if each $P_j$ is continuous, then $P$ is continuous as well and $(P_j)$ converges uniformly to $P$ on compact subsets of $E$.

It's easy to prove (1), and the first part of item (2) is a consequence of the Principle of Uniform Boundedness to homogeneous polynomials:

**Theorem:** A subset of $\mathcal{P}_a(^mE;F)$ is norm bounded if and only if it is pointwise bounded.

I couldn't prove the uniform convergence over a compact subset $K\subset E$, can anyone help me? I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you solve that yet? I'm going to renew the bounty for you if not. :)

Comment: I am still not able to prove the assertion and i would apreciate if you could do it. :)

Comment: Alright, you should probably ask that on math.overflow :P